# Piping multiple files into $variable

Tags: bash

I've attempted to sort through various threads online and am having trouble determining how to pipe output into a subsequent command. I am using batch scripting (via bash) to concatenate multiple files through an independent program, which requires the input to be in a particular format.

The standard command for concatenation within the program is:

```
fslmerge -t $OUTPUT $INPUT1 $INPUT2... $INPUT n
```

I've tried several ways to define the input files, with the most recent attempt below.

```
file=$INPUTDIR/sublist.txt
  while read -r SUBJ; do

for cond in "med" "nomed"; do

for n in {01..10}; do

INPUT="stage2_${SUBJ}_${cond}_00${n}.nii.gz"

fslmerge -t $OUTPUT/stage2_ic00${n}_${cond}.nii.gz `ls $INPUTDIR/$INPUT`

done; done; done < $file
```

However, this results in running the command on each input separately vs. running the command on all inputs (as noted above in the "standard command"):

```
fslmerge -t $OUTPUT $INPUTDIR/subject1
fslmerge -t $OUTPUT $INPUTDIR/subject2
...
fslmerge -t $OUTPUT $INPUTDIR/subject10
```

EDIT:
The sublist.txt is listed as follows. They are stacked in the order that I need them to be concatenated via `fslmerge`.

```
SUB003  
SUB006  
SUB007  
SUB010  
SUB011  
SUB001  
SUB004  
SUB008  
SUB009
```

For each condition (med, no med), each subject has multiple components (n). Ultimately, I need to have the command run so that it concatenates all subjects for a given condition and component. An example would be:

```
fslmerge -t $OUTDIR/stage2_ic0001_med.nii.gz stage2_SUB003_med_0001.nii.gz stage2_SUB006_med_0001.nii.gz stage2_SUB007_med_0001.nii.gz ... stage2_SUB009_med_0001.nii.gz
```

I'd be very grateful for any input on the issue and/or methods for simplifying! And I'm relatively new at coding, so sincere apologies for any terminology errors. I realize my attempts are probably grossly out of this world.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want it to do? Particularly, should it run `fslmerge` once for each line in sublist.txt, or twice for each line (once with cond="med", and once with cond="nomed"), or twenty times (once for each combination of cond and n)? If it's the last of those, what are the input files (you seem to show only one input per SUBJ/cond/n combination); if it's not the last, what're the output files supposed to be (you seem to show cond, and n as part of the filename).

Comment: The general idea would be to add all the input filename to an array, then use `"${array[@]}"` to put all of them at the end of the command. But I also don't understand how you want to do this, since your output file is different for each input file.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks so much for your help! Your questions are excellent, and I think this is where I am messing up, as well being generally confused about how to proceed.  It is the last of the examples you give: Each subject (SUBJ) has two conditions (med, no med). For each condition, each subject has multiple component files (n).

Comment: I basically need to batch the command, so it would output as such for each condition and component: `fslmerge -t stage2_ic0001_med.nii.gz stage2_$sub001_med_0001.nii.gz stage2_$sub002_med_0001.nii.gz ... stage2_$sub010_med_0001.nii.gz`

Comment: Can you edit your question to show an example of the input you're working with (presumably the `sublist.txt` file) and the desired commands you want to end up running?

Comment: OK, I have edited as requested-- hopefully this helps to clarify what I need (and if not, happy to add more). Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding right, you want to run the command for each cond/n combination, and merge the input files for all subjects (i.e. everyone listed in sublist.txt). Is that right? If so, what I'd do is store all of the subjects in an array, then use that array to generate the list of input files for each subject:

```
subjectsfile=$INPUTDIR/sublist.txt
subjects=()
inputfileprefixes=()
while read -r subj; do
    subjects+=("$subj") # this isn't really needed, since we don't use the list directly.
    inputfileprefixes+=("$INPUTDIR/stage2_$subj")
done <"$subjectsfile"

for cond in "med" "nomed"; do
    for n in {1..20}; do
        fslmerge -t "$OUTPUT/stage2_ic00${n}_${cond}.nii.gz" "${inputfileprefixes[@]/%/_${cond}_00${n}.nii.gz}"
    done
done
```

There's some slightly heavy array trickery here. The stuff like `"${arrayname[@]/%/something}"` takes an array, and tacks "something" to the end of each element. So say the subjects are "alice", "bob", and "cecil", and INPUTDIR is "/some/path". Then `subjects` gets set to `("alice" "bob" "cecil")`, `inputfileprefixes` gets set to `("/some/path/stage2_alice" "/some/path/stage2_bob" "/some/path/stage2_cecil")`, and the for each cond/n combination it tacks on the appropriate suffix and passes that list to `fslmerge`, so the command comes out like `fslmerge -t $OUTPUT/stage2_ic001_med.nii.gz /some/path/stage2_alice_med_001.nii.gz /some/path/stage2_bob_med_001.nii.gz /some/path/stage2_cecil_med_001.nii.gz`.

Warning: this is not fully tested, and I'm not entirely sure I understand the question right. Back up everything important before running this, in case it does something silly.

BTW, I recommend against using all-caps variable names (there are some that're reserved, and you'll use one of those by mistake, and weird things will happen). Also, it's a good idea to double-quote strings that include variable expansions (like I did with `"$OUTPUT/stage2_ic00${n}_${cond}.nii.gz"`), in case the variables' values contain spaces or other shell metacharacters.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `inputfileprefixes+=("$INPUTDIR/stage2_$subj")` directly in the first loop?

Comment: @Gordon: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly, and I really appreciate you taking the time to explain everything, particularly as I seem to be having difficulty articulating the issue. Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks as well @melpomene!